# mv *.{jpg,png} folder/ works only when both filetypes are present

Tags: terminal, mv

Isn't `*.{jpg,png}` supposed to select every file of any of those types?

I know `mv` can accept targets in succession like this `mv *.png *.jpg folder/`, but why `{}` doesn't work this way?

Comment: `echo *.{jpg,png}` would have easily shown you what the problem is.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the problem. It's not that `{}` isn't working, it's that `mv` is returning an error when it can't find anything to match `*.jpeg` or `*.png`. The way you have constructed your command, there must be at least one file to satisfy both conditions for the command to complete without an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore "no matches" from zsh when using brace expansion with glob \*.{a,b,}test](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407532/ignore-no-matches-from-zsh-when-using-brace-expansion-with-glob-a-b-test)

Comment: See also: [Avoiding non-zero exit code when running `ls` using multiple patterns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693003/avoiding-non-zero-exit-code-when-running-ls-using-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Answer (score 0):

Brace expansion isn't part of filename globs, it's a distinct feature and works before globbing happens.

First, brace expansion turns `*.{jpg,png}` into `*.jpg` and `*.png`. Then, filename globbing expands both of them to any matching filenames. By default, glob patterns that don't match any files, are left as-is. So, both of these are equal:

```
mv *.png *.jpg folder/
mv *.{png,jpg} folder/
```

If the only files to exist in the directory are `foo.png` and `bar.png`, both commands expand to

```
mv foo.png bar.png *.jpg folder/
```

and `mv` will probably complain about the nonexisting file `*.jpg`.

Assuming you're using Bash, you should instead enable extended globs with `shopt -s extglob`, and use the extended glob `*.(png|jpg)`. It does what you want, but is actually one glob, not two. Alternatively, you could set `shopt -s nullglob`, which would make the non-matching globs disappear instead of being left as-is.

If at least one file of either type exists, the result is the same for both. If none exist at all, `*.(png|jpg)` would be left as-is like that if `nullglob` is disabled. With `nullglob` on, the patterns would disappear completely, turning the command into just `mv folder/`. The error message from that might be confusing.