# Ignore "no matches" from zsh when using brace expansion with glob *.{a,b,}test

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, wildcards, brace-expansion

I would like to list all of the files in a folder called `foldername` that have the extension `test`, `atest` or `btest`.

My immediate thought was to run `ls ./foldername/*.{a,b,}test`

This works fine unless there is nothing with the extension `atest`, in which case I get the error `zsh: no matches found: ./foldername/*.atest`.

Is there any way I can simply ignore this error and print the files that do exist?

I need this to work in both zsh and Bash.

Comment: Redirect standard error to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be best to do this with `find`:

```
find ./foldername -maxdepth 1 -name '*.atest' -o -name '*.btest' -o -name '*.test'
```

Comment: perhaps with a `-maxdepth 1`, to closer emulate the `ls` behavior

Comment: @JeffSchaller, note that `-maxdepth` is a GNU extension. Note 3 other differences with globs: `find` would include hidden files, not sort the list and fail to match file names that contain bytes not forming valid characters (like a `$'St\xe9phane.atest'` in a UTF-8 locale)

Answer (score 15):

In

```sh
ls -d ./foldername/*.{a,b,}test
```

`{a,b,...}` is not a glob operator, that's brace  expansion, that's first expanded to:

```sh
ls -d ./foldername/*.atest ./foldername/*.btest ./foldername/*.test
```

And each glob expanded individually, and if any glob doesn't match, the command is cancelled as you'd expect in `zsh` (or `fish`; in `bash`, you need the `failglob` option to get a similar behaviour).

Here, you'd want to use a single glob that matches all those files, and only cancel the command if that one glob didn't match any file:

```sh
ls -d ./foldername/*.(a|b|)test
```

You don't want to use `nullglob`, as if none of the globs matched, it would run `ls` without arguments, so list the current directory. `cshnullglob` is better in that regard as it removes non-matching globs but still cancels the command if all the globs fail to match.

You wouldn't want to use `nonomatch`, as that would give you the broken behaviour of `bash` which would be a shame.

For a glob alternative that works in both `zsh` and `bash`, you could use the ksh globs (`set -o kshglob` in `zsh` and `shopt -s extglob` in `bash`).

Then, you'd do:

```sh
ls -d ./foldername/*.@(a|b|)test
```

or:

```sh
ls -d ./foldername/*.?([ab])test
```

Add the `failglob` option in `bash` to avoid the glob being passed literally to `ls` when it doesn't match.

See [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803) for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a requirement of the OP, but is there an extglob that works for this in both bash and zsh? I had to use `?(...)` or `+(...)` for bash.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, see edit

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, and first solved it by hacking ls itself. When finished, I realised that all I needed was the trival C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct stat statbuf;
  int i;
  for( i=1; i<argc; i++ ) {
    if( stat(argv[i],&statbuf) == 0 ) {
      printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

All this does, and all it needs to do, is to run through its command line arguments and echo those strings that correspond to valid files (that is, for which stat() succeeds).

Of course, we can emulate this with equally simple Python, Perl, or even a shell function that runs stat, but writing it in C makes it much quicker to run.

As for hacking ls, I've put a run through on my personal wiki: http://linux.chalisque.net/LsIgnoreMissing

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @DopeGhoti worked for me.

i.e. Redirecting the error to `/dev/null` using `2>` operator like so:

```
ls ./foldername/*.{a,b,}test 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't work in zsh where this question is about as you'd only be redirecting `ls`' stderr, and `ls` is not even run here in zsh if any of those globs fail.