# Avoiding non-zero exit code when running `ls` using multiple patterns

Tags: bash, wildcards, tcsh, brace-expansion, pattern-matching

Say I have two possible paths I want to list directories and files under on a Linux machine:

```
/some/path1/
/some/path2/
```

If I do the following in `tcsh`, I get `0` exit code, if at least one of `path1` or `path2` exists:

```
ls -d /some/{path1,path2}/*
```

But if I do the exact same thing in `bash`, I get `2` exit code, with a `stderr` message reporting `path1` does not exist (if path1 is the one that doesn't exist).

How can I make `bash` behave like `tcsh` in this case? Is there a switch to `ls` that I can ask it to give back `0` if at least one path exists? If neither one exists, I do expect non-zero code, which is what `tcsh` gives back.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what you are seeing because that seems very unlikely - the exit code is coming from `ls`, and ls doesn't care whether it's being executed by bash or tcsh (also, i tested it on my system, and got an exit code of 2 in both bash and tcsh).   In any case, you probably don't want to be relying on ls to check whether a directory exists or not.  Use `test -d dir` (or`[ -d dir ]` - `[`).  If you need to test existence of more than one, you can use boolean `&&` or `||` operators to combine tests, or use a for loop.

Comment: @cas you need to test with `{foo,bar}/*`, the `/*` makes the difference. It's a `nullglob` issue.

Comment: In `zsh`, you can use `set -o cshnullglob` to enable the csh behaviour, though you'd rather do `ls -d (foo|bar)/*` there. See also [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Comment: See also: [Ignore "no matches" from zsh when using brace expansion with glob *.{a,b,}test](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407532/ignore-no-matches-from-zsh-when-using-brace-expansion-with-glob-a-b-test)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most of your questions are already answered at [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803).

One thing to bear in mind is that:

```
ls -d /some/{path1,path2}/*
```

In `csh`/`tcsh`/`zsh`/`bash`/`ksh` (but not `fish`, see below) is the same as:

```
ls -d /some/path1/* /some/path2/*
```

As the brace expansion is performed *before* (not *as part of*) the glob expansion, it's the shell that expands those `/some/pathx/*` patterns into the list of matching files to pass as separate arguments to `ls`.

`bash`, like `ksh` which it mostly copied has inherited a misfeature introduced by the Bourne shell in that, when a glob pattern doesn't match any file, it is passed as-is, literally as an argument to the command.

So, in those shells, if `/some/path1/*` matches at least one file and `/some/path2/*` matches none, `ls` will be called with `-d`, `/some/path1/file1`, `/some/path1/file2` and a literal `/some/path2/*` as arguments. As the `/some/path2/*` file doesn't exist, `ls` will report an error.

`csh` behaves like in the early Unix versions, where globs were not performed by the shell but by a `/etc/glob` helper utility (which gave their name to globs). That helper would perform the glob expansions before invoking the command and report a `No match` error without running the command if *all* the glob patterns failed to match any file. Otherwise, as long as there was at least one glob with matches, all the non-matching ones would simply be removed.

So in our example above, with `csh` / `tcsh` or the ancient Thompson shell and its `/etc/glob` helper, `ls` would be called with `-d`, `/some/path1/file1` and `/some/path1/file2` only, and would likely succeed (as long as `/some/path1` is searchable).

`zsh` is both a Korn-like and csh-like shell. It does not have that misfeature of the Bourne shell whereby unmatched globs are passed as is¹, but by default is stricter than `csh` in that, all failing globs are considered as a fatal error. So in `zsh`, by default, if either `/some/path1/*` or `/some/path2/*` (or both) fails to match, the command is aborted. A similar behaviour can be enabled in the `bash` shell with the `failglob` option².

That makes for more predictable / consistent behaviours but means that you can run into that problem when you want to pass more than one glob expansion to a command and would not like it to fail as long as one of the globs succeeds. You can however set the `cshnullglob` option to get a csh-like behaviour (or `emulate csh`).

That can be done locally by using an anonymous function:

```
() { set -o localoptions -o cshnullglob; ls -d /some/{path1,path2}/*; }
```

Or just using a subshell:

```
(set -o cshnullglob; ls -d /some/{path1,path2}/*)
```

However here, instead of using two globs, you could use one that matches all of them using the alternation glob operator:

```
ls -d /some/(path1|path2)/*
```

Here, you could even do:

```
ls -d /some/path[12]/*
```

In `bash`, you can enable the `extglob` option for bash to support a subset of ksh's extended glob operator, including alternation:

```
(shopt -s extglob; ls -d /some/@(path1|path2)/*)
```

Now, because of that misfeature inherited from the Bourne shell, if that glob doesn't match any file, `/some/@(path1|path2)/*` would be passed as-is to `ls` and `ls` could end up listing a file called literally `/some/@(path1|path2)/*`, so you'd also want to enable the `failglob` option to guard against that:

```
(shopt -s extglob failglob; ls -d /some/@(path1|path2)/*)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `nullglob` option (which `bash` copied from `zsh`) for *all* non-matching globs to expand to nothing. But:

```
(shopt -s nullglob; ls -d /some/path1/* /some/path2/*)
```

Would be wrong in the special case of the `ls` command, which, if not passed any argument lists `.`. You could however use `nullglob` to store the glob expansion into an array, and only call `ls` with the member of the arrays as argument if it is non-empty:

```
(
  shopt -s nullglob
  files=( /some/path1/* /some/path2/* )
  if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
    ls -d -- "${files[@]}"
  else
    echo >&2 No match
    exit 2
  fi
)
```

In `zsh`, instead of enabling `nullglob` globally, you can enable it on a per-glob basis with the `(N)` glob qualifier (which inspired ksh's `~(N)`, not copied by `bash` yet), and use an anonymous function again instead of an array:

```
() {
  (( $# > 0 )) && ls -d -- "$@"
} /some/path1/*(N) /some/path2/*(N)
```

The `fish` shell now behaves similarly to `zsh` where failing globs cause an error, except when the glob is used with `for`, `set` (which is used to assign arrays) or `count` where it behaves in a `nullglob` fashion instead.

Also, in `fish`, the brace expansion though not a glob operator in itself is done as part of globbing, or at least a command is not aborted when brace expansion is combined with globbing and at least one element can be returned.

So, in `fish`:

```
ls -d /some/{path1,path2}/*
```

Would end up in effect behaving like in `csh`.

Even:

```
{ls,-d,/xx*}
```

Would result in `ls` being called with `-d` alone if `/xx*` was not matched instead of failing (behaving differently from csh in this instance).

In any case, if it's just to `print` the matching file paths, you don't need `ls`. In `zsh`, you could use its `print` builtin to print in columns:

```
print -rC3 /some/{path1,path2}/*(N)
```

Would print the paths `r`aw on 3 columns (and print nothing if there's no match with the `N`ullglob glob qualifier).

If instead you want to check if there's at least one non-hidden file in any of those two directories, you can do:

```
# bash
if (shopt -s nullglob; set -- /some/path1/* /some/path2/*; (($#))); then
   echo yes
else
   echo no
fi
```

Or using a function:

```
has_non_hidden_files() (
  shopt -s nullglob
  set -- "$1"/*
  (($#))
)
if has_non_hidden_files /some/path1 || has_non_hidden_files /some/path2
then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

```
# zsh
if ()(($#)) /some/path1/*(N) /some/path2/*(N); then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

Or with a function:

```
has_non_hidden_files() ()(($#)) $1/*(NY1)
if has_non_hidden_files /some/path1 || has_non_hidden_files /some/path2
then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

(`Y1` as an optimisation to stop after finding the first file)

Beware those `has_non_hidden_files` would (silently) return false for directories that are not readable by the user (whether they have files or not). In `zsh`, you could detect this kind of situation with its `$ERRNO` special variable.

---

<sup>¹ The Bourne behaviour (which was specified by POSIX) can be enabled though in `zsh` by doing `emulate sh` or `emulate ksh` or with `set +o nomatch`</sup>

<sup>² beware there are significant differences in behaviour as to what exactly is cancelled when the glob doesn't match, the `fish` behaviour being generally the more sensible, and the `bash -O failglob` probably the worst</sup>

Comment: The quality of this response is staggering! Thanks for taking the time to write such a beautifully detailed answer. Enjoyed reading it!

Comment: Although not everyone might like the POSIX/Bash default of passing unmatched globs through literally, I think calling it a "misfeature" is a bit strong. Of course general scripts meant to be portable should not rely on it and always quote everything not meant to be expanded, but interactively it's nice to save some keystrokes in cases like `dnf upgrade kernel*`.

Comment: @TooTea, and then you do that in a directory where someone (maybe last year's you) made a file called `kernel-versions.txt`, and start wondering why it doesn't work. As long as we don't have meta-information about what the program is expecting as arguments (filenames or something else), all we can do is to do it manually. (It's just one backslash there, too) Leaving the glob as-is lets you have error messages like "ls: cannot access '*.foobar': No such file or directory" which looks nice, but even that's misleading, since it hides the fact that the shell does the globbing, not ls.

Comment: @ilkkachu Of course that does happen,but it only takes you by surprise the first few times and then you get used to it. It's less work to just go back and add quotes/backslashes in the 1% of situations where the wildcard happens to match something.

Answer (score 4):

Just read [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693039/22222).

---

This happens because of how `bash` treats globs that do not match anything. To get the same behavior you observe in `tcsh`, you need to enable bash's `nulglob` option. From `man bash`:

> nullglob
>
> If  set, bash allows patterns which match no files
> (see Pathname Expansion above) to expand to a null string,
> rather than themselves.

Enable `nullglob` with `shopt -s nullglob` and you will get the expected behavior:

```
$ ls
bar
$ ls {bar,foo}/*
ls: cannot access 'foo/*': No such file or directory
 bar/ff
$ echo $?
2


$ shopt -s nullglob 
$ ls {bar,foo}/*
bar/ff
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: You don't want nullglob here. If neither pattern matches, you'll end up listing the current working directory. See [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803). You'd rather want `shopt -s failglob extglob` and `ls -d @(foo|bar)/*` (with the shell reporting an error when there's no match like in tcsh, instead of passing the `@(foo|bar)/*` literally (which could very well be the name of an existing file) to `ls` as `bash` does by default without `failglob`.

Comment: With `nullglob`, you could do: `files=( {bar,foo}/* ); (( ${#files[@]} )) && ls -d -- "${files[@]}"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sounds like a great answer.